# Error while removing array element

Tags: java, arraylist

I have new arraylist, 1 arraylist which has 10 customer already inserted.  I'm running a loop which picks a random customer from the arraylist and adds it into the 2nd arraylist. However, I'm getting duplicates when I insert customer into the 2nd arraylist. So when the loop runs after adding the customer into the 2nd arraylist it will remove it from the 1st arraylist.

However, when it runs I get an error: `Intervals error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7, Size: 7`

```
ArrayList<String> customer = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(list));

int customerlist = customer.size();

while (line.isEmpty())
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < customerlist; x++ )
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(intervals * 1000);   //Sleep method to hold the arrival time by 1-2 seconds. 
                    int cus = (int) (Math.random() * customerlist);   //Random customer is picked here. 
                    String new_cus = customer.get(cus);   //New customer object is created ere.
                    line.add(new_cus);   //Customer objects are added to the empty LinkedList queue.
                    customer.remove(cus);

                    //For loop statement to outputting the queue.
                    for (String s : line)
                    {
                        System.out.print("[" + s.toString() + " " + "]"); //Outputting each customer and using the ".name" method so customers are readable.
                    }
                    //Outputting the whole queue and stating who has joined the queue.
                    System.out.println("\n" + "The queue has " + line.size() + " customers so far" + "\n" + 
                    new_cus.toString() + " Has Joined the Queue " + " <=== WAITING" + "\n");
                }
                catch(Exception e)   //ERROR handler for sleep method.
                {
                    System.out.println("Intervals error: " + e);   //Outputting the ERROR message.
                    System.exit(0);   //If ERROR found exit system.
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Try flooring the value of `cus`.

Comment: Are you just trying to put the given customers into a list in a random order?

Comment: Basically im trying to remove duplicate customer being added into my 2nd arraylist, but I need the customer to be randomly picked in the first place.

Comment: Give us an example of what `customer` could be beforehand and what you would like `line` to look like afterward

Answer (score 1):

You are removing from the array you are effectively iterating over, yet not updating the condition accordingly.

Change:

```
for (int x = 0; x < customerlist; x++)
```

to

```
for (int x = 0; x < customer.size(); x++)
```

(Or better yet, use an iterator over the underlying `ArrayList` so that you can remove safely using the `Iterator.remove()` function.)

Also change the line:

```
int cus = (int) (Math.random() * customerlist);
```

to

```
int cus = (int) (Math.random() * customer.size());
```

Comment: I dont understand can you explain it please.

Comment: Oki im not getting a error however I need 10 customer to be added to the 2nd arraylist with the code you given me its only adding 5 customers. It worked to get 10 customer i just changed the loop value i < 10; Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
int cus = (int) (Math.random() * customerlist);
```

That's fine (although not as clean as calling [`Random.nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)) for the first iteration - but afterwards, `customer.size()` has changed (as the element has been removed) but `customerlist` is still the same. So on the next iteration, you're picking an element in the wrong range.

To be honest, you'd be better off just using [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) to shuffle the original list - that's the result you want in the end, right?

Answer (score 1):

add

```
customerlist--;
```

after

```
customer.remove(cus);
```

also, you can change

```
for (int x = 0; x < customerlist; x++)
```

by

```
for (int x = 0; x < customer.size(); x++)
```

but I think a call to the `.size` function at every loop uses more resources than a local variable.

Comment: This made it work aswell but I dont understand what does this mean customerlist--;

Comment: this means customerlist = customerlist - 1;

Comment: Thanks every I understand what I did wrong it was basically the customer.size() every time loop runs I need record the length of the arraylist with my pervious code this value was 10 even doe I kept removing customers from it. My bad !!! lol got ti working thanks again